# How to make a logic app to run once and call the api multiple times

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

[image]

I want to run this logic app once and it needs to hit the api endpoint 50 times. I want to implement this to check some caching policy in API Management.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-branches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to run this logic app once and it needs to hit the api endpoint
> 50 times

You can design a logic app such as below , based on screenshot we are using variables to keep the count until loop ,Inside which for each iteration we can have a http activity to invoke in API .

[image]

For more information you can also refer this Microsoft documentation: [Call service endpoints over HTTP or HTTPS from Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http)